SDLog - looking for papers
Reading trough SEC 1 V2.0 in txe appendices there is a mention of a elliptic curve semi logarithm (ECSLP) being used to forge ECDSA signatures.
I am looking for papers on that problem and have been unable to find anything more than DRL Browns paper referenced in SEC 1 where he defines the problem as being:
Given ECDSAs reduction function $$f:R.x\rightarrow r$$
the semi logarithm is a pair $(t,u)$ satisfying $$t=f(u^{-1}×(G+t×P)).$$
Is the problem known under another name or is this particular problem not seen as a threat?
From my understanding the hardness of the problem should be equal to the DLog problem.
If you know of the problem kindly point me in the direction of the papers on it.

Please fix the equations if in error.

That is the name the problem is known as. It may also be seen as forging an ECDSA signature without signing queries and having a message such that $H(m) = 1$. See Limits in the Provable Security of ECDSA Signatures and the references therein for the current understanding of this problem.
